# sphinx get non-stemmed results

Tags: sphinx

When I query sphinx, it first applies stemming to my input keywords and gives me back a set of results with words that matched. The problem is that the result keywords are also stemmed.

Is there a way to get back from sphinx the original search keyword and not the stemmed one. For example, if I do a batch query with the following words:

- credit card
- working
- walked

and suppose sphinx found a match for credit card. The problem is that sphinx returns me "cred card" and I have to manually check (by comparing strings) with which one of the above keywords the document(s) matched. And this could be very inefficient in my circumstances.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I posted the same question on the sphinx forum and someone answered. So here it is: the sphinx results get back in the same order as the queries were added, so it is easy to get to the original keywords! Hope this can help to others ...

Comment: Can you provide link to that question ??

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=10106

Comment: yeah, it's the above link ... sorry i didn't reply immediatly.